# Get dynamic data interpreted from a set of preseted conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have some data from manufacturer to interpret COP of a heat pump:

```
outsideTemp: 7, targetTemp: 35, kWpdc: 15, COP: 3.96
outsideTemp: 7, targetTemp: 45, kWpdc: 13.2, COP: 3.11
outsideTemp: 2, targetTemp: 35, kWpdc: 12.6, COP: 3.58
outsideTemp: -15, targetTemp: 35, kWpdc: 8.7, COP: 2.12
```

If: `outsideTemp: 3.5, targetTemp: 42, kWpdc: ??, COP: ??`

I am using JavaScript to work with, I am trying this code:

```
// Define kWpdc & COP
const temperatureConditions = [
    { outsideTemp: 7, targetTemp: 35, kWpdc: 15, COP: 3.96 },
    { outsideTemp: 7, targetTemp: 45, kWpdc: 13.2, COP: 3.11 },
    { outsideTemp: 2, targetTemp: 35, kWpdc: 12.6, COP: 3.58 },
    { outsideTemp: -15, targetTemp: 35, kWpdc: 8.7, COP: 2.12 }
];

// Data of Outside Temp & Target Temperature
const outsideTemp = 7;
const targetTemp = 35;

// Inițializing kWpdc & COP
let kWpdc = null;
let COP = null;

// Finding values using conditions
for (const condition of temperatureConditions) {
    if (condition.outsideTemp === outsideTemp && condition.targetTemp === targetTemp) {
        kWpdc = condition.kWpdc;
        COP = condition.COP;
        break;
    }
}
```

With my code I get the results only if `outsideTemp` & `targetTemp` are preciseley in `temperatureConditions`

Comment: Isn't it what you programmed in `if (condition.outsideTemp === outsideTemp && condition.targetTemp === targetTemp)`?

Comment: Yes it is, but I wish to have dynamic interpret of the `COP` & `kWpdc`

Comment: Then you need to update your code accordingly. Decide how exactly you would obtain such *dynamic* values first.

Comment: There is the problem, what whould be the way to interpret data? any ideas?

Comment: Does the manufacturer ever send the data differently? I'm struggling to understand what the use case for 'outsideTemp' and 'targetTemp' to not be specified - do you mean you want to be able to receive more data and then check that, as opposed to your static array?

Comment: That has nothing to do with programming. This is domain knowledge that should come out of physics or some special science.

Comment: `outsideTemp` & `targetTemp` data are coming from 2 sensors in real time, but `temperatureConditions` is a list from manufaturer to understand `kWpdc` & `COP` range